# Can we stop datastax-agent process in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I know datastax-agent is used to show to data in opscenter.  But if we aren't using it, can we stop the datastax-agent process?  Does it have any other use?

We are using Cassandra 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `datastax-agent` is only used for OpsCenter. Its fine to stop the process. Just be aware that you might see errors in OpsCenter for that node, if you are still using it.

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter is [not compatible](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/opscPolicyChanges.html) with open source Cassandra 3.x and there should not be a running datastax-agent service in 3.7. OpsCenter 6.0 only works with DSE Cassandra.